# Does the size of a log file affect the processing time of loging with the Logger class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, performance, logging, filesize

I'm using the Logger class in Ruby's standard library.
http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_logging.html
I rotate a log file weekly.

If the size of a log file become larger, will the processing time of loging become longer?
Or will more CPU or memory be required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just going to append to the end of the log file, it's not like it reads the log file in or anything :)